# Overriding visible value in Application class and then showing main form causes stack overflow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to make a program that will play a startup sound (because Microsoft hates them now apparently) and that requires the form to be completely hidden when the program starts, so it's just sound but I also need to access the form in order to change settings when I need to, to successfully hide the form I use this code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        Me.CreateHandle()
        value = False
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
End Sub
```

Which, from my understanding overrides startup in the Application class and prevents the startup form from starting, but I've made it so that it only plays the sound if a `-t` argument is passed through a shortcut, so I can access the main form to change settings easier when I need to, here is what the full code looks like so you can get a better idea of what I'm talking about

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        Me.CreateHandle()
        value = False
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    Dim clArgs() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If clArgs.Count() = 2 Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To 1 Step 1
            If clArgs(i) = "-t" Then
                Try
                    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Settings.startSound, AudioPlayMode.Background)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Else
                Me.Show()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

So to summarize what happens here, it will start by checking if there is a `-t` argument passed in `CommandLineArgs` and if there is, it will play the sound, without actually starting up the form, but if there isn't, it will startup the form, but for some reason, if I have `Me.show()` in the code, it will cause a stack overflow, and I have no clue as to why this happens apart from that this form hiding code is the one that causes it

Comment: Do you mean that you get a stack overflow only when the `Me.Show()` is executed? The `Me.Show()` is equivalent to set `.Visible = True` in the form ([reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.show?view=netframework-4.8)), is there any case at all in which you're able to successfully display the form?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using either the VB Application.Startup event or disabling the VB application framework and writing your own `Sub Main` to process the command line argments?